# Is there a good resource for learning about the sum-of-digits functions?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

The digit sum with respect to a base $n$ of a natural number $r$ is defined as the sum of the digits when $r$ is written in base $n$. Lets write this $\sigma_n(r),$ which gives us a family of functions $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, one for each $n$. For instance, $\sigma_2(4) = 1$, because $4$ written in binary is $100$, so the sum of the digits is $1$. It seems to be hard to get information about these $\sigma_n$ functions.

> **Question.** Is there a good resource for learning about the digit sum functions?
>
> For instance, I'd like to know the following kinds of things:
>
> - What can we say about $\sigma_n(a+b)$ and $\sigma_n(ab)$?
> - If $p$ is prime, can we say anything about $\sigma_p$?
> - Are there interesting properties of numbers can be characterized in a natural way by the properties of $\sigma_n$?
> - etc.

I'm also interested in the generalization of these maps in which the digits are weighted, so that rather than just summing them up, we take some kind of a linear combination.

Comment: If you know German, there is
Jan-Christoph Puchta, Jürgen Spilker, Altes und Neues zur Quersumme, 
http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/~schlage-puchta/papers/Quersumme.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Only few facts seems to be known. You can have a look at:

A. Balog and C. Dartyge, On the sum of the digits of multiples, Moscow J. Comb. Number Th. 2 (2012), 3–15.

L. E. Bush, An asymptotic formula for the average sum of the digits of integers, Amer. Math. Monthly 47 (1940), 154–156

Or this curious reference where I found the two others: Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol 15, Article 12.8.1 by Carlo Sanna